# SQL / XPATH - How to select all possible elements that have the same name into separate rows/columns

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I need to select all the elements under a specific node, all the elements have the same name.

## Tables

Lets say I have 2 tables in my database;

1. [Access_Groups], This table contains all the groups that can access my application
2. [User_Accounts], This table contains user details and an XML file that contains their access groups

I want to see which users have access groups in their XML file, that match the groups in my [Access_Groups] table

## XML File

The XML files in [User_Accounts] look like this:

```
<Profile>
    <Name>John Smith</Name>
    <Role>Developer</Role>
</Profile>
<Groups>
    <String>Group_1</String>
    <String>Group_2</String>
    <String>Group_3</String>
    <String>Group_4</String>
    <String>Group_5</String>
    <String>Group_6</String>
</Groups>
```

## Query

If i run this following query:

```
SELECT [XML].value('(//Groups)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS 'XML'
FROM [User_Accounts]
```

I will get the following result:

| XML |
| --- |
| Group_1Group_2Group_3Group_4Group_5Group_6 |

This is of no use to me as i cannot JOIN this table to [Access_Groups]

If I run this query instead:

```
SELECT 
[XML].value('(//Groups/*)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS 'XMl_1',
[XML].value('(//Groups/*)[2]', 'varchar(max)') AS 'XMl_2',
[XML].value('(//Groups/*)[3]', 'varchar(max)') AS 'XMl_3',
[XML].value('(//Groups/*)[4]', 'varchar(max)') AS 'XMl_4',
[XML].value('(//Groups/*)[5]', 'varchar(max)') AS 'XMl_5',
[XML].value('(//Groups/*)[6]', 'varchar(max)') AS 'XMl_6'
FROM [User_Accounts]
```

I will get the following result:

| XML_1 | XML_2 | XML_3 | XML_4 | XML_5 | XML_6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Group_1 | Group_2 | Group_3 | Group_4 | Group_5 | Group_6 |

I could JOIN this results set to [Access_Groups], However this is no use to me as i have to define every single column. Some users may have up to 100 groups.

## Solution

Is there no way i can do something like this?:

```
SELECT [Name], 
[XML].value('(//Groups)[*]', 'varchar(max)') AS 'XML'
FROM [User_Accounts]
```

To get a result set like this:

| Name | XML |
| --- | --- |
| John Smith | Group_1 |
| John Smith | Group_2 |
| John Smith | Group_3 |
| John Smith | Group_4 |
| John Smith | Group_5 |
| John Smith | Group_6 |

I could then SELECT FROM that results set WHERE IN (SELECT * FROM [ACCESS_GROUPS]) to determine if this user had access to my application

Obviously though:

```
SELECT [Name], 
[XML].value('(//Groups)[*]', 'varchar(max)') AS 'XML'
FROM [User_Accounts]
```

This does not work!

Has anyone got any idea of how i could compare all the 'String' nodes for each user to my [Access_Groups] table?

Thanks!

*This is my first post, so it might be a bit rubbish*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, you need to use [`nodes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver16) to expand your XML into rows, e.g.

```
DECLARE @User_Accounts TABLE ([XML] XML);
INSERT @User_Accounts ([XML]) VALUES('<Profile>
    <Name>John Smith</Name>
    <Role>Developer</Role>
</Profile>
<Groups>
    <String>Group_1</String>
    <String>Group_2</String>
    <String>Group_3</String>
    <String>Group_4</String>
    <String>Group_5</String>
    <String>Group_6</String>
</Groups>');


SELECT  Name = ua.[XML].value('(Profile/Name/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
        Role = ua.[XML].value('(Profile/Role/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
        GroupName = g.x.value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)')
FROM    @User_Accounts AS ua
CROSS APPLY ua.[XML].nodes('/Groups/String') AS g (x);
```

**[Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e62882adbcac2d9fbaf5dc9b2782a76c)**

Comment: Thank you for the assistance.
I don't think I am understanding this properly though.

I am writing something like this:  

**SELECT
ua.[XML].value('(//Profile/Name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS 'Name',
ua.[XML].value('(//Group)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS 'GroupName
FROM [User_Accounts] ua
CROSS APPLY ua.[XML].nodes('/Groups/String') g**

Here CROSS APPLY doesn't seem to recognise the [XML] column from [User_Accounts] table and I'm not sure if .Nodes is valid in my version of t-sql as it doesn't highlight in blue as .Value does

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? I'd be surprised if it is not supported. If what you have posted is exactly what you are running then you are missing a bit at the end where you give your XML data an alias e.g. I have posted `AS g (x)` you only have ` AS g`. To try and make this easier for you I have updated the example in the question and in the db<>fiddle to match your table structure so you *should* now be able to copy and paste the code with minimal changes and get it running

Comment: Aha, it took a little bit of playing around to understand what was happening but I've cracked it. Cannot thank you enough, as this has been bothering for a while!